Simulating and testing MAR missing data mechanism - check my logic
I am wanting to show what missing at random data might look like and so I have tried to simulate some and also show how you can theoretically test for it. I'm wanting to check that:

My simulation is reasonable.
My logic for testing for MAR, and furthermore for MCAR within MAR categories, is also reasonable.

Any help would be appreciated.
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# Simulation
n <- 1000                                           # set number of obs to simulate
set.seed(1234)                                      # set seed for reproducibility
age <-  rnorm(n, 40, 10)                            # generate age variable - mean = 40, SD = 10
sex <-  rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)                           # generate sex variable ~ 50% females (0) and 50% males (1)

# Generate bodyweight from regression model based on additive effects of sex and age - on average, males are 5 kg heavier than females and each year increase in age is associated with a 3 kg increase in bodyweight
# Thus, this model is NOT realistic - 
# When sex and age = 0, bodyweight = 5, but as this is assumed to increase linearly with age, an average 70 year old would weigh 215 kg for females and 220 kg for males. A quadratic function of age would be more appropriate, but lets keep things simple...
bodyweight <-  5 + 5 * sex + 3 * age + rnorm(n, 0, 1)

# Check that we recover the original coefficients:
dat <-  data.frame(sex = sex, age = age, bodyweight = bodyweight)
summary(lm(bodyweight ~ age + sex , data = dat))

# Now, let's create some missingness at random (where the missingness in bodyweight depends on sex)
# The model intercept and coefficient have been selected so that the probability of missingness will be ~ 12% for males and ~ 73% for females
logodds_missing <-  1 - 3 * sex                      
odds_missing <-  exp(logodds_missing)
prob_missing  <-  odds_missing/(1 + odds_missing)
binary_missing <-  rbinom(n, 1, prob_missing)
dat <- cbind(dat, odds_missing = odds_missing, prob_missing = prob_missing, binary_missing = binary_missing)

# Check with tabulation
table(dat$prob, dat$binary_missing)
# This is about right
0.119*515 # gives 61 males with missingness
0.731*485 # gives 354 females with missingness

# Test for an association between missingness and sex (MAR)
# Step 1 - test whether missingness depends on sex
mod_sex <- glm(binary_missing ~ sex, data = dat, family = "binomial")
broom::tidy(mod_sex, exp = T)  # i.e. there's an ~ 95% reduction in the odds of having missingness in bodyweight for males relative to females and this is significant
# Step 2 - now test whether missingness depends on bodyweight WITHIN each category of sex - i.e. missingness is random (MCAR) within categories
mod_females <- glm(binary_missing ~ bodyweight, data = subset(dat, sex == 0), family = "binomial")
tidy(mod_females, exp = T) # i.e. missingness does not depend on bodyweight for females
mod_males <- glm(binary_missing ~ bodyweight, data = subset(dat, sex == 1), family = "binomial")
tidy(mod_males, exp = T) # i.e. missingness does not depend on bodyweight for males

# Test for an association between missingness and age (MCAR)
mod_age <- glm(binary_missing ~ age, data = dat, family = "binomial")
tidy(mod_age, exp = T) # i.e. missingness does not depend on age

P.S. I understand that testing for the missing data mechanism has limited potential in that if a test is positive, it could be MNAR as well as MAR; and if the test is negative, it could be MNAR as well as MCAR, but I just want to check what I have done in the current context is ok.
